# How to capture repeating group in Sublime-syntax

Tags: regex

I've searched high and low but have been unable to find a solution for this.

I need to parse a statement in subline-syntax.  That statement is as such

Sum(#,#[,#]*)

In other words, the keyword Sum must be followed by ( then one pair of numbers separated by a comma and zero or more numbers prefixed with a comma and finally closing with ).

I am using regex101 to test with the python regex (which what I've read that sublime's regex is based on).

https://regex101.com/r/TzKxIp/2

Comment: SublimeText S&R is PCRE based. [Change the option.](https://regex101.com/r/9zzjTO/1)

Comment: Even if sublime text used Python regular expressions, `(?<name>...)` syntax would not be a native Python's regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - that helped a little.  the regex matches all of the parameters as a group as expected, but still only matches the last group as a value.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/TzKxIp/3 - updated for pcre

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? If you don't need the capturing groups you could use `\bSum\(\d+(?:\s*,\d+)*\)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NgxoOk/1/)

Comment: @Thefourthbird - I do need the capture groups to extract the constants.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja Do you mean like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fsskQ6/1/) where all the constants are in the third capturing group?

Comment: @Thefourthbird - I need each constant value

Answer (score 0):

To find all the digits in a capturing group you could use and [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with `\G` to get an iterative match.

`(?:\bSum\((?=\d+(?:,\d+)*\))|\G(?!\A))\K(\d+),?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zribo6/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\bSum\(` A word boundary followed by Sum(
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what follows

    - `\d+(?:,\d+)*\)` Match a digit followed by repeating zero or more times a comma and a digit followed by `)`
  - `)` Close positive lookahead
  - `|\G(?!\A)` Or assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\K` Forget what has been matched
- `(\d+),?` Match a digit with an optional comma